# How to get all values from datediff function using oledb query and the data come from excel file has been imported

Tags: vb.net

I want to show all values from excel using `oledb query datediff` which one will use data from `date created` and `last login < 20` to show all values in that conditition, but I got problem using datediff query. I dontknow how to use datediff query using excel data values. Can anybody help me?

This is the code :

```
dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$] WHERE
   datediff(FORMAT([Last Login Date], 'dd/mm/yyyy'),FORMAT([Last Login
   Date], 'dd/mm/yyyy')) > 20", conn)
```

Comment: you're not specifying the interval (ie, day, year, month, etc...)  [datediff](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp) and I don't think you need the format, let datediff perform the calculation off of the date format the database is using. They are date types in the table, right?

Comment: yes, but the value each other is diferent "last login date"  = 12/10/2018  16:47:43, "create date" 01/10/2018.

Comment: it said : exception unhandled = no value given for one or more required parameters. this is my new code : dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$] WHERE datediff(day,[Last Login Date],[Date Active / Create Date]) > 90", conn)

Comment: What is [Date Active / Create Date] is that an actual column heading? If so, are you sure it's exaclty that spelling. Your error usually means there is a field that it doesn't recognize so it assumes it's a parameter.

Comment: Actually, I gave you the wrong link for OleDb [here is one](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php) that should work. Notice the difference in the format of the function for interval.

Comment: I also think you have your dates reversed by your example, this would produce a negative number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say your new code is:

```
dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$] WHERE datediff(day,[Last Login Date],[Date Active / Create Date]) > 90", conn)
```

According to the specs you should use `d` instead of `day` for the first parameter value of your call to `DateDiff`.

And you should put it inside quotes, so `"d"` instead of just `d`.

But to use quotes inside a string variable in VB.NET, you should double the quotes. Like this: `""d""`.

So you might try this:

```
dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$] WHERE datediff(""d"",[Last Login Date],[Date Active / Create Date]) > 90", conn)
```

Does this work for you?

Edit: Also mark @CharlesMay's comment about switching the date fields for getting a positive value.

Edit 2:

Since you are executing this query over an OleDb connection from VB.NET, it might be the case that you need to use single quotes inside the query.

```
dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$] WHERE datediff('d',[Last Login Date],[Date Active / Create Date]) > 90", conn)
```

I am not sure, however. I am currently not able to test it. These are all just suggestions.

Comment: You're welcome. :) If my answer solved your problem, you might mark it as correctly answered. Otherwise other people might be confused and think your question still needs an (other) answer.